# How to convert a character to string using a function that has character as argument and returns string?

Tags: c

I had problem while using a function to do the task.Do I need to pass a pointer to character as well to do the task.I used the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>    
char* change(char c)    
{    
     char s[2];    
    s[0]=c;    
    s[1]='\0';    
    return s;    
}

int main()    
{    
    char t='o';    
    char* kk;    
    kk=change(t);    
    printf("\n%s",kk);    
    return 0;    

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable from a function without making a copy. Two ways of doing what you need in `C` are

- Asking the caller to provide a buffer for writing the string, and returning the length, and
- Allocating the return value dynamically with `malloc` or an equivalent, and requiring the caller to `free` the resultant string.

Here is the first approach:

```
int change(char c, char* res, int len) {
    if (len < 2) return -1; // Invalid parameters
    res[0]=c;
    res[1]='\0';
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the second approach:

```
char* change(char c) {
    char *res = malloc(2);
    res[0]=c;
    res[1]='\0';
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* change1(char c){
    static char s[2];
    s[0]=c;
    return s;
}

char* change2(char c){
    char *s = malloc(2);
    s[0]=c;
    s[1]='\0';
    return s;
}

char* change3(char c, char *s){
    s[0]=c;
    s[1]='\0';
    return s;
}


int main() {
    char t='o';
    char* kk;
    kk=change1(t);
    printf("%s\n", kk);

    kk=change2(t);
    printf("%s\n", kk);
    free(kk);

    char s[2];
    kk = change3(t, s);
    printf("%s\n", kk);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
char s[2];
```

to

```
char *s; s = malloc(2);
```

and your program should work fine.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to `free()` that returned pointer later.

Comment: a warning stating implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' gets displayed.

Comment: Thats because I havent done a case conversion here ... `s = (char *) malloc(2);`. However, it shouldnt be a porblem for your code.